# Small radical of polynomial at integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

Let $f(x)$ be squarefree polynomial with coprime integer coefficients.
Assume $\deg f > 1$.

For natural $N$
define $G(f,N) = \#\{X : 1 \le X \le N, |X|^{\deg(f)-1 } \ge rad(f(X))\}$

where $rad(A)$ is the radical of $A$, the product of the prime factors of $A$.

> How large can $G(f,N)$ be for some $f$? Can we get $G(f,N) \sim \log^\alpha{(N)}$ for $\alpha > 1$.

For $f=x(x-1)$ and $X=p^m$ for small $p$ and large $m$ we get 
$G(f,N) \sim \log{(N)}$.

Another approach to get a near miss is solve $F(X) \mod p^m =0$,
then the radical is at most $\frac{p f(X)}{p^m}$.

We think abc implies that $G(f,N)$ can't be as large as 
$n^\alpha,\alpha>0$ for all $f$,can we show this unconditionally?

Experimentally $G(x^4+1,10^5)= 2, G(x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4),10^5)=4887$